# How can I lock a rotation matrix to the horizon?

Tags: matrix, camera, rotation, geometry

I have problem with 3x3 rotation matrix. Is that possible to adjust an arbitrary existing rotation matrix, so the rotation was locked to the horizon (no roll, just pitch and jaw)? I need to make the horizon be always "horizontal", like with camera in some FPS, for example.

Comment: Only rotate about the "up" axis, maybe? I'm having trouble visualizing your question. Can you elaborate and maybe give us example matrices for your current transformation and what you want to do next?

Comment: The problem is that I need not only rotation around "up" axis, but also around "to-right" axis. The matrix, let's say, is a random orthogonal rotation matrix. Need to "remove" from it rotation around "forwards/backwards" axis.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question thinking you just wanted to keep yaw. Example matrices, even symbolic ones, would still be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transform an existing rotation matrix to a rotation matrix constrained as you want (that is the right vector of the rotation matrix is always in the plane normal to the up axis of your world coordinate system) unambiguously, you have to specify how the transformation should take place? The existing rotation matrix can be rotated about a whole bunch of vectors to get the constraint that you want, but they can all give you a different result.

Probably the most natural vector to rotate about would be the forward vector of your existing rotation matrix, but it might also be the forward or right vector of your world coordinate system.

I'll give you an example of rotating about the forward vector of your existing rotation matrix. I'm going to assume you are using a coordinate system like the default OpenGL coordinate system where X is right, Y is up and Z is backwards, if your coordinate system is different you'll have to adjust for it.

You would have the following world to object rotation matrix:

```
[r1 u1 b1]
[r2 u2 b2]
[r3 u3 b3]
```

with `r*`, `u*`, and `b*` being orthogonal right, up, and back vectors respectively of your rotated object coordinate system expressed in your world coordinate system.

As said you want to constrain the right vector to the plane normal to the up axis of your world coordinate system, that means that `r2` should always be `0`. Now we cannot just set `r2` to `0`, that would give you a very weird deformation instead of a clean rotation. We have to find some angle to rotate with that will get the right vector in the right plane.

Your adjustment would look like:

```
[nr1 nu1 nb1]     [r1 u1 b1]     [ar1 au1 ab1]
[nr2 nu2 nb2]  =  [r2 u2 b2]  *  [ar2 au2 ab2]
[nr3 nu3 nb3]     [r3 u3 b3]     [ar3 au3 ab3]
```

where `a*` is your adjustment and `n*` is your new rotation matrix.

The `a*` rotation matrix will now basically just be a rotation around the forward vector (Z axis) of an angle theta to get the `r*` vector back into the plane orthogonal to the up vector of the world coordinate system. That theta can be calculated by the dot product between `<r1, r2, r3>` and `<r1, 0, r3>`.

```
dotproduct(<r1, r2, r3>, <r1, 0, r3>) == length(<r1, r2, r3>) * length(<r1, 0, r3>) * cos(theta)

theta = acos(dotproduct(<r1, r2, r3>, <r1, 0, r3>) / (length(<r1, r2, r3>) * length(<r1, 0, r3>)))
```

Then rotation matrix `a*` is just the rotation matrix as applied by `glRotate3f(theta, 0, 0, 1)` Or maybe `-1` for the last argument, too tired to think about it now.

Note that if you do your own pitch and yaw applications on user input it is way easier to just calculate a world to object rotation matrix every frame you render the object instead of maintaining an incremental transformation matrix, (which could even get into gimbal lock.) In that case just adjust the pitch and yaw numbers upon use input and then make sure to apply pitch and yaw in the correct order, yaw first then pitch, if you do it the other way around you will get roll as a side effect.

Comment: Thanks for reply, that was very useful! However, didn't worked for me in its initial version. Also, probaly the most valuable thing for me was the note about the reason of appearing roll side effect, due to incorrect order of yaw and pitch.

Comment: Yes, as noted, it depends on your transformation matrix representation and your choice of world axes. Sometimes the right, up and forward/backward vectors are in the rows instead of in the columns like in OpenGL, sometimes people use opposite axes, sometimes people use Z to be the world up axis instead of Y as in OpenGL, for all these things you need to adjust.

Comment: And yes, if you use a different order for rotations you get a different effect, the rotation that you execute is relative to the transformations up to that point, so if you already pitched forward, then the yaw will be about an up vector that is leaning forward, not about the up vector of your world coordinate system, leading to an implicit roll. The other way around you first turn horizontally to face the direction that you want and then pitch forward in that direction.